# Php While Loop 3 : 4 Grid

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Having some problems with print output like alternative rows 3 : 4 column.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while($i=1 < 14){
 if($i <= 3){
   echo $i."<br>";
 } else {
   echo $i."<br>";
 }
 $i++;
}

?>
```

** I Want Output Like **

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 
11 12 13 14
```

Comment: That `if` clause looks a little "useless" if it prints the same output in the `else` branch, you could just remove it

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo (remainder of a division). Apply a modulo 7 on `$i`:

```
for ($i=1; $i<15; $i++) {
    echo $i, in_array($i % 7, [0, 3]) ? '<br>' : ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 
11 12 13 14
```

you can just try this,

```
$firstRow = 0;
$secondRow = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++){
   $firstRow++; 
   $secondRow++;

   echo $i . ' ';

   if($firstRow == 3){
      echo '<br>';
      $secondRow = 0;
   }
   if($secondRow == 4){
      echo '<br>';
      $firstRow = 0;
      $secondRow = 0;
   }
}
```